# "¿Cómo puedo establecer el valor de un elemento select2 utilizando la información contenida en una fila (rowData) de un DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, select2

Actualmente, estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
    $("#" + selectId).val(rowData.category).trigger('change');
```

Cabe aclarar, que tengo dos selects que se llenan dinamicamente uno en diferente modal, aqui el detalle lo tengo cuando tomo la dat de la fila y no setea el valor que tiene dicha fila pero realmente rowData si met trae correctamente el valor de la categoria en la fila.
Estas son mis funciones que he creado:

```
// Evento de clic para el botón de editar en la DataTable
$("#dataTable_products tbody").on("click", ".editar-btn", function () {
    var rowData = dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr")).data();
    console.log(rowData)
    openModalEdit(rowData, 'editcategoria');
});

//Aqui es donde seteo mis valores
function openModalEdit(rowData, selectId) {

    getCategories('editProductModal', selectId);

    $("#editbarCode").val(rowData.barcode);
    $("#editdescription").val(rowData.description);
    $("#editmarca").val(rowData.marca);
    $("#editmodelo").val(rowData.model);
    $("#" + selectId).val(rowData.category).trigger('change');
    $("#editinv_min").val(rowData.inventory_min);

    // Asigna la ruta de la imagen al atributo "src"
    $("#editImage").attr("src", rowData.image);

    // Abre el modal de edición
    $("#editProductModal").modal("show");
}

// Función para obtener las categorías desde el controlador
function getCategories(modalId,selectId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+'/category',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            if (response && response.data && response.data.categories) {
                const categoriasData = response.data.categories;
                // Inicializar select2 con las opciones obtenidas y abrir el modal
                initSelect2(categoriasData, modalId,selectId);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error('Error al obtener las categorías desde el controlador:', error);
        }
    });
}

// Función para inicializar Select2 y abrir el modal
function initSelect2(categoriasData, modalId, selectId) {
    const selectCategoria = $('#' + modalId).find('#' + selectId);
    console.log('Inicializando selec2 for: ',selectId)

    selectCategoria.select2({
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
                return "No se encontraron resultados";
            }
        },
        data: categoriasData.map(categoria => ({
            id: categoria.id_category,
            text: categoria.name
        }))
    });
}
```

Espero puedan apoyarme en este detalle que tengo